# Multiapp Taskbar Grouping on Windows 7+

Tags: c#, windows-7, taskbar

Let me layout the scenario.

We have a 3rd party application (say, app.exe installed to C:\App).  It actually cannot run directly, it needs a configuration file passed to it as an argument: "C:\App\app.exe config.ini".  Everyone already has shortcuts that contain the necessary arguments.

This application supports plugins, of which we have developed a few.  In order to distribute said plugins, they need to be copied to each users C:\App\Plugin\ folder, so when a change is made I have to travel around to everyone's desk and make sure the update gets applied.

This was cumbersome, so I developed an application that will scan a network folder and compare it to it's internal db of files.  If there are any changes, it copies the files over to the proper destination folder.

This wasn't seamless though, as the user would have to make sure app.exe was closed - run my updater, and then rerun app.exe.  So I renamed the original app.exe to app_launcher.exe, and my updater to app.exe.  I modified my updater application to support arguments and pass them through to app_launcher.exe when the update was done.  Once app_launcher.exe has started the updater program closes.

I should note - the above actually works.

The problem comes from users who have the app shortcut pinned to the taskbar.  Once the real app finally starts it gets it's own new icon on the taskbar instead of being grouped with the original shortcut.  This actually makes sense as they are technically two different applications.  The users however, don't like this.

I have done some research on this, and found some 3rd party programs that can allow you to group multiple programs (Bins/Fences). I DO NOT WANT THIS.

More research revealed something called the AppUserModelID, which intrigued me.  After some playing around, I got my updater to set it's own AppUserModelID.  The original app.exe didn't set it's AppUserModelID (found that out via ProcessHacker), but I was able to get the updater to start it with the same ID it was using via the CreateProcess method found in kernel32.dll.

This did NOT work.  The updater started under it's own pinned icon, and the original app started a new icon.  I tweaked the updater to stay open until the original app was closed to see if that made a difference.  This time it started under it's own pinned icon, the original app started it's own, and then the updater window switched to be grouped with the original app under the new icon.  So AppUserModelID did group them together, but not how I wanted.

I am using C# for the updater application, and cannot make changes to (or have changes made to) the original app.

How can I get these applications to group under the pinned shortcut?  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think I may have found a solution, though it's a bit of a hack.

The problem comes from having the final application not matching the shortcut being run.

So rather than replacing the EXE and running the real one when done, I made sure the updater application would always run before the real exe.

The only caveat is that it also runs for EVERY exe on the system (via HKCR\exefile).  The first parameter is now the path to the true executable, which if it matches the application it runs the updater.  Once the updater finishes or if it is any other app, it runs it.

Not an ideal solution (as it could be detected as malware), but it should work for us.

Comment: OK - this solution doesn't really work well either.  It prevents some system tools from running.  Some Intel programs on startup (igfx stuff) and also msconfig.  Apparently the updater program when triggered via these programs thinks that the programs don't exist.